# Double free or memory corruption

Tags: c++, free

I have a code like this

```
char *verboseBuf = NULL;
if(somethin){
    for(a loop){
        for(another loop){
            if(somethin else){
                if(curl execution){
                    if(fail){
                        verboseBuf = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char) * (currSize +1));
                        fread(verboseBuf, 1, currSize, verboseFd);
                        verboseBuf[currSize + 1] = '\0';
                        string verbose = verboseBuf;
                        free(verboseBuf);
                    }   
                }   
            }   
        }   
    }   
}
```

The only place that i use the verboseBuf is inside the final if loop. but i get

```
*** glibc detected *** ./test: double free or corruption (!prev): 0x13c13290 ***
```

But how can be freeing it twice if i only use it in one place? and everytime i use it, i free it.
I tried using addr2line to find the place where it was freed previously but all got was a `??:0`.

Comment: If you are coding in c++ you should prefer to use new and delete. Also you might want to consider using RAII or other memory management techniques that are more idiomatic in c++.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This line is writing one byte past the end of your buffer.

```
verboseBuf[currSize + 1] = '\0';
```

Answer (score 3):

That message doesn't specifically mean that you freed something twice, it means that glibc detected heap corruption, and freeing things twice is *one* common cause of that, but not the only one.

In this case, the line

```
verboseBuf[currSize + 1] = '\0';
```

is overflowing the end of your buffer, corrupting whatever bookkeeping data the allocator stored after it.  Remove the +1 and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Make `verboseBuf[currSize + 1] = '\0';` as `verboseBuf[currSize] = '\0';`